# Replace DateTime column value where date is greater than other date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am attempting to replace all DateTime values in a certain column where the date is greater than a particular date.

An example of the `df` is shown below.

```
date
2016-01-03
2016-01-03
2016-01-03
2016-01-02
2016-01-02
2016-01-02
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2015-12-31
2015-12-31
2015-12-31
```

I would like all dates to greater than `2016-01-01` to appear as `2016-01-01`.

My desired expected output is shown below.

```
date
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2016-01-01
2015-12-31
2015-12-31
2015-12-31
```

Any assistance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df.loc[df['date'].gt('2016-01-01'), 'date'] = pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) with datetime - e.g. with `Timestamp`:

```
#if necessary
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'].clip(upper=pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'))
print (df)
         date
0  2016-01-01
1  2016-01-01
2  2016-01-01
3  2016-01-01
4  2016-01-01
5  2016-01-01
6  2016-01-01
7  2016-01-01
8  2015-12-31
9  2015-12-31
10 2015-12-31
```

Comment: Funny, clip is smart enough to correctly do the fancy comparison with just '2016-01-01', but replaces it with the string

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I will do `mask` , only different here between `clip` and `mask` ,when the replace value is same as boundary value , `clip` is better, however, when you have different replace value mask can do it better.

```
df.date.mask(df.date.gt('2016-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'),inplace=True)
df
Out[397]: 
         date
0  2016-01-01
1  2016-01-01
2  2016-01-01
3  2016-01-01
4  2016-01-01
5  2016-01-01
6  2016-01-01
7  2016-01-01
8  2015-12-31
9  2015-12-31
10 2015-12-31
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!